# How to add data from database to table in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a table

```
  Table table = new Table();
  table.setHeight("100%");
  table.addContainerProperty("First Name", String.class, null);
  table.addContainerProperty("Last Name", String.class, null);
  table.addContainerProperty("Year", Integer.class, null);
```

And i want to fill this table data from data base (PostgreSQL) . Can you give me example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [SQLContainer](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-sqlcontainer) and [JPAContainer](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-jpacontainer). JPAContainer also has a pretty nice [tutorial](http://vaadin.com/download/jpacontainer-tutorial/).

I'd recommend SQLContainer for smaller applications and JPAContainer for larger applications. SQLContainer is integrated in the Vaadin core from version 6.7 upwards.